# Why does easy_install ouput an error in jython2.7?

Tags: python, jython, easy-install, jython-2.7

I installed jython2.7.2 on Windows10. It works fine.

But module installation raised always the same error.
For example ( https://jython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/appendixA/), `easy_install python-twitter`, failed with the following error

> ...
> ...
> File "E:\jython2.7.2\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1730, in auto_chmod
> six.reraise(et, (ev[0], ev[1] + (" %s %s" % (func, arg))))
> IndexError: index out of range: 1

Did someone have the same problem and how did you solve it ?
Thanks for answer.

Comment: Did you follow the steps on the site? Which `setuptools` version is installed? (Also note that jython2.7 is unmaintained I think. If you can use something else like a jython3, I would strongly recommend that)

Comment: @Megalng. I installed the current version [https://www.jython.org/installation ], `java -jar jython-installer-2.7.2.jar`

Comment: @Melgalng. setuptools version is 41.0.1. jython3 is not the current version. For my project, I have to use jython. Otherwise, I use python 3.9

Comment: Could you post the full traceback? This is not the actual source of the error but only a symptom.

Comment: @Megalng [https://pastebin.com/YYw8BWyi ]

Comment: Did you try pip instead of easy_install?

Comment: I tried easy_install

Comment: Then I think you should try pip. It worked for me.

Comment: With pip, I have a new error message : *ImportError: No module named _winreg*. OS : W10

Comment: pip works for me. I'm also on WIndows 10 with Jython 2.7.2. I don't have any other suggestions, sorry.